# Is there a way to see activity for all my Tumblr blogs in one place?

Tags: tumblr

I like the Tumblr activity pane, but there's no decent way to flip through the activity for all of my various tumblrs. I even tried making a little page on `localhost` that iframes them all but Tumblr redirects out of the iframe.

Has anyone found a good way to look at their whole Tumblr activity, not just per blog?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have any sideblogs so I can't test anything, but [**XKit**](http://www.xkit.info/seven/) (with the Activity+ extension) might make it easier to flip through activity for your different blogs.

*(There's an option for Activity+ that says "When I switch my blog on the sidebar, go to the Activity page of that blog" which might help.)*